# Python Wikipedia library

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I'm using python library Wikipedia to parse data. When its get to the second part of the code I'm getting page errors.[Page Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuywq.jpg)

```
import wikipedia


print ("1: Searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus vehicles'")
try:
    print (wikipedia.page('List of Lexus'))
    print ('-' * 60)
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    print (str(e))
    print ('+' * 60)
    print ('DisambiguationError: The page name is ambiguous')
print


print ("2: Searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus (vehicles)'")
print (wikipedia.page('List of Lexus_(vehicles)'))
print


result = wikipedia.page('List of Lexus_(vehicles)').content.encode('UTF8')
print ("3: Result of searching Wikipedia for 'List of Lexus_(vehicles)':")
print (result)
print

lexus_count = result.count('ct','lfa','rx')
print


print ("The Wikipedia page for 'Lexus_(company)' has " + \
    "{} occurrences of the word 'Lexus'".format(lexus_count))
print
```

Updated 
I'm able to parse page data but getting Type error on count

```
23 print
24
25 lexus_count = result.count('ct','lfa','rx')
26 print
TypError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Comment: Please copy & paste the errors you're getting into your question instead of posting an image of text.

Comment: Well when I search for Lexus (company) on Wikipedia the result reads: 'The page "Lexus (company)" does not exist. You can ask for it to be created, but consider checking the search results below to see whether the topic is already covered.' So the error message makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was multiple issues with your program. Here is an updated program, with the errors fixed and marked.

```
import wikipedia


print ("1: Searching Wikipedia for 'Lexus'")
try:
    print (wikipedia.page('Lexus'))
    print ('-' * 60)
except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
    print (str(e))
    print ('+' * 60)
    print ('DisambiguationError: The page name is ambiguous')
print


print ("2: Searching Wikipedia for 'Lexus (company)'")
result = wikipedia.page('Lexus (company)') 
# ERR; PAGE NAME SEPARATED BY SPACE NOT WITH AN UNDERSCORE
# <> PAGE ERROR AS PAGE WILL NOT BE FOUND.  
print (result)
print


result = result.content
print ("3: Result of searching Wikipedia for 'Lexus_(company)':")
print (result)
print

lexus_count = result.count('Lexus')
# changed variable name from orange_count -> lexus_count, as referenced in the print function below. 
# you were counting for 'lexus' you will not find any occurrences as this function is case sensitive.
print


print ("The Wikipedia page for 'Lexus_(company)' has " + \
    "{} occurrences of the word 'Lexus'".format(lexus_count))
print
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @M_S yes according to https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/ there is a python3.7 package.

Answer (score 0):

Which page error exactly are you getting?

According to the wikipedia documentation: https://wikipedia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#quickstart

> But watch out - wikipedia.summary will raise a DisambiguationError if the page is a disambiguation page, or a PageError if the page doesn’t exist (although by default, it tries to find the page you meant with suggest and search.):